How to hidden panel in specific story in storybook version 8.2.5
I have this config for me story
export default {
  title: Classes',
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  parameters: {
    options: {
      showPanel: false,
    },
  },
}

This worked in version 6.X but in this version 8.2.5 doesnt work, i tried this but dont work
export default {
  title: 'Utilities/Classes',
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  parameters: {
    toobar: {
      disabled: true,
    },
  },
}```

